# Removing keywords from an SQL string

Tags: python

I have this sample sql query in a string and I have put the SQL keywords in a list. I want to iterate through both lists and split at the occurance of a word from keywords.

The code I have given does not work.

```py
sql = 'SELECT BRAND_ID, count(ACC_START_DATE) as count_ACC_START_DATE FROM Backbook History WHERE PD_RAW >= 0.9 GROUP BY BRAND_ID ORDER BY BRAND_ID'
keywords = ["SELECT", "FROM", "GROUP BY", "ORDER BY", "WHERE"]
split_sql = sql.split()
new_sql = None
for word in split_sql:
    for item in sql:
        if word == item:
            new_sql = sql.split(word)
```

Comment: what is your exopected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your nested for loop you are iterating over *letters* in your sql string:

```
 for word in split_sql:
    for item in sql:
```

use:

```
for word in split_sql:
    for item in keywords:
```

full code:

```
sql = 'SELECT BRAND_ID, count(ACC_START_DATE) as count_ACC_START_DATE FROM Backbook History WHERE PD_RAW >= 0.9 GROUP BY BRAND_ID ORDER BY BRAND_ID'
keywords = ["SELECT", "FROM", "GROUP BY", "ORDER BY", "WHERE"]
split_sql = sql.split()

new_sql = [] # define empty lists
for word in split_sql:
    for item in keywords:
        if word == item:
            new_sql += sql.split(word) 

print (new_sql)
```

output:

```
['', ' BRAND_ID, count(ACC_START_DATE) as count_ACC_START_DATE FROM Backbook History WHERE PD_RAW >= 0.9 GROUP BY BRAND_ID ORDER BY BRAND_ID', 'SELECT BRAND_ID, count(ACC_START_DATE) as count_ACC_START_DATE ', ' Backbook History WHERE PD_RAW >= 0.9 GROUP BY BRAND_ID ORDER BY BRAND_ID', 'SELECT BRAND_ID, count(ACC_START_DATE) as count_ACC_START_DATE FROM Backbook History ', ' PD_RAW >= 0.9 GROUP BY BRAND_ID ORDER BY BRAND_ID']
```

Comment: My mistake. 

Is there a way to get those 3 sentences in 1. A.k.a. 1 list which does not contain the keywords ?

Comment: Check my edit :)